# AngularJS - On selecting date from angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker url state removing from browser URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I am using angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker.

On clicking on date picker for selection of date & time.

The current state is removing from browser URL. How to resolve this?

`HTML` code

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="startDate" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="#">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input placeholder="{{'START_DATE' | translate}} *" required type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="startDate"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <datetimepicker data-on-set-time="onStartDateSet(newDate, oldDate)" date-disabled="disableViewFields" data-ng-model="startDate" data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#startDate', startView:'day', minView:'hour' }" />
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code of the controller and the HTML of the page?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're not hitting the <a> above the datepicker when you set a date with it? Try removing the <a> and see what happens

Comment: Only <a> tag - can I remove? Inside html too?

Comment: Yes, remove the whole 
<a class="dropdown-toggle" id="startDate" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="#">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input placeholder="{{'START_DATE' | translate}} *" required type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="startDate"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
    </a> 
from HTML and see what happens

Comment: Date picker not showing, its hided, if I remove <a> tag section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I removed href='#' from a tag, working fine. Code follows

```
<div class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" id="startDate" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input placeholder="{{'START_DATE' | translate}} *" required type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="startDate"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <datetimepicker data-on-set-time="onStartDateSet(newDate, oldDate)" date-disabled="disableViewFields" data-ng-model="startDate" data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#startDate', startView:'day', minView:'hour' }" />
</ul>
```